# error: libaudit.h: No such file or directory

Tags: linux-kernel, audit, openwrt, auditing, libselinux

I am building libselinux on openwrt, and need auditing support.
But I have really open the aduditing support in the linux kernel menuconfig, why still this error happen?

```
error: libaudit.h: No such file or directory.
```

Any sort of help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What exact configuraton option you set for enable auditing support? What exact file cause this error?

Comment: I have finally get this passed myself. The reason is that I have make a wrong install commands in my makefile. I have not copy libaudit.h to the correct dir. Thanks, @Tsyvarev.